# Rotate fill color by group in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I need to have each record to rotate background fill in SSRS but each record is grouped into two rows, I have tried the solution that others have used but they are not working.

This is the expression I have tried:

```
=IIf(RowNumber(Nothing) Mod 2 = 0, "Silver", "Transparent")
```

It seems odd because it looks like its working but about the 6th group down it will put two groups together with the same color. so this needs some sort of adjustment.

Comment: Which solution would that be? Please edit the question to include what you have tried already.

Comment: Does your report have more than one level of grouping?